# Applied mathematics: Is there a way to characterize transient warmup time to reduce settling time errors?

Tags: numerical-methods, error-propagation

I don't know if this is the right place to post this but

I have an electronic sensor that measures conductance using Conductance = I/V.
The results are very good especially with a Newton Raphson filtering algorithm.
However there is a warmup time of the circuit itself of approximately 4 minutes before getting peak performance, as seen below., (Xaxis in seconds)

For each individual sensor reading there will be a warmup time if the system isn't running for 4 minutes or longer.

In some ways 4 minutes is way too long.
Is there a way to capture the first 30 readings and mathematically characterize the transient warmup time? Or characterize the trajectory?

That way, instant readings under 4 minutes can be calibrated out to be closer to peak performance?

[image]

Comment: @nicomezi I was thinking more about characterizing the raw transient data. But sure: Newton Raphson filtering : beta = 0.5 * Exp[- Ntau]. The raw data is called f(Xn+1) at the new step; f(Xn) is the unfiltered raw data at the previous step.

Solve for alpha:

alpha = 1 - 2 * beta. The ‘filtered’ output, Xn+1, is:

Xn+1 = (alpha * Xn) + beta * [ f(Xn+1)+ f(Xn)]

Comment: I mean, you can always fit some function, in your case a second order linear system might do the trick (looks like a bit of overshooting, so you wanna have eigenvalues with nonzero complex part). The problem is that small differences in the initial slope will have large differences for the final steady state value. And you got a lot of noise thus you cannot estimate the slope very well and thus also not the dual value, sophisticated tricks cannot  help too much here...

Comment: @nicomezi The point of the filtering method was to show that the resolution of the sensor was good past the warm-up time. The warm-up time requires 4 minutes so therefore causes complications. An instant result has a 300ppm error. If I were to characterize the trajectory I could calibrate it out with a lookup table or something.

Comment: @NeitherNor Thanks that sounds like what I want. How would I start to do this? Especially with the eigenvalues and nonzero complex part, it has been a long time since my differential equations and linear algebra course. I think that it is worth a shot to see experimentally how small differences in the initial slope will take. Let's say on sensor turn on I take 50 readings, Enough readings may be enough to remove the effect of the noise. The standard error is like 50ppm, the peak to peak variation is about 285ppm. I don't know how to define the 'noise' or if the standard error defines it

Comment: At the end, all you do is curve fitting. The trick is to guess a good type of curve which can describe the dynamics well but is not overparametrized. I only guessed that a good choice might be a curve which is the solution to a second order linear ODE. These have the form $y(t)=c_0+c_1e^{-\lambda t}cos(\mu t+\phi)$. Probably $\lambda$, $\mu$ and $\phi$ are always the same in your experiments, so you can estimate them from many existing (full) trajectories. $c_1$ and $c_0$ must then be estimated from the transient dynamics in every experiment separately. You are interested in $c_0$.

Comment: @nicomezi: I think what Jirhska wants to do is to guess the steady state value given only the first few measurements where there are still transient dynamics. At the end, he has a sensor which takes some time to equilibrate. He doesn't want to wait this time but use the fact that in the transient dynamics there is already information hidden to which value they will converge.

Comment: Let me start from the beginning. You want to fit a function, fine. But looking at values after a few minutes seems to indicates the "final" measurement is not clear at all, there are even more outliers at some point. I am sure I would rely on fitting a second order linear system solution here, even without considering stability problems by only using the first readings. Unless you have a very good reason to use such assumption and if you possess information about the noise you are observing on your measurements.

Comment: A good reason would be to have an equation clearly stating the evolution of that dynamic system, and in this case I would rather use Kalman filters, as I already said in a deleted comments (for cleaner comment section).

Comment: @NeitherNor the 2nd order  y(t)=c0+c1e^(−λt)cos(μt+ϕ).   Estimating c0 and c1 seems to be the trick. c1 is what appears to be the slope and c0 to be the starting value? I suppose without my foolish conjectures of what they are, my question is how to estimate them with lets say 100 initial readings.

Comment: @nicomezi thank you, yes it appears so, but let it be known that these are very small values. I am measuring a 1 ohm resistor with this sensor, 1/R = conductance. so the noise is like 300uSiemens or 300ppm and the STDev is about 50ppm. So the most obtainable value is in there somewhere. And anything in that 1 to 3 sigma area should be acceptable

Comment: $c_0$ is the final value. That's what you are interested in. Easiest would be to simply use some curve fitting toolbox. Many programming languages have them ready to use. You can of course also go for Kalman filters or so, but I think it's a bit overdozed (you don't want to continuously estimate the end point, it's a one shot estimate after the first 100 data points, right?). Which programming language are you using? But I repeat my warning from above: the whole thing will likely work not very well, since you are basing most of your estimate on a first derivative of a noisy curve...

Comment: @NeitherNor So it seems if I can estimate the system, lambda, mew, and phi, which  is due to temperature equilibrium because the current flowing through the opamps causes heat, I only need C1. So what is c1? 

I am mostly operating out of Excel right now. I have access to matlab but eventually the algorithm must be programmed in raw C. I appreciate the warning but I wouldn't be happy with myself if I didn't try it out. I have done kalman filtering before but am not fluent with it enough to estimate the end point.

Comment: Again, you want to get $c_0$! Why are you even interested in $c_1$? It's just some variable you need for the fitting function which you afterwards throw away. I don't know Excel too much, but in matlab the command you want to take a look on is "fit": https://de.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/fit.html#bto2vuv-11

Comment: @NeitherNor Sorry I fumbled there, I don't know how else to solve for the constants. I will look into the matlab function. I was just interested in solving the fitting myself because essentially I would have to put the algorithm in C. Preferably I would do it this way because my application is on an embedded controller so memory is very important to conserve. I suppose I could use my existing data to solve for the c1e^(−λt)cos(μt+ϕ) term during the warm up phase?

Comment: You would only solve for $c_0$ and $c_1$ in the controller. There should be some simple algos in C available, too. The rest of the variables you would determine a priori in Matlab using fit and hard code into the C program (I think they won't change too much between measurements, only $c_0$ and $c_1$ will). I think you don't understand the concept of fitting: (i) you give matlab the data, (ii) the function, and (iii) Matlab returns the values of the variables. You don't have to "solve" anything yourself. I would test everything first offline in Matlab. If it doesn't work, you save coding in C.